# RegEx on HTML string, get a specific region

Tags: html, regex

I would like to get a specific region on a HTML string, but I'm only able to get "the third region" instead of the second.
Let me specify :

The HTML string :

```
<tr><td><STRONG>A.Total Likuiditas Tersedia (Net)</STRONG> </td><td class='text-left'>297,860</td><td class='text-left'>175,236</td><td class='text-left'>166,774</td></tr>
```

And I would like to extract only (knowing that the figures change everyday):

```
<td class='text-left'>175,236</td>
```

I tried to match with this Regex :

```
<td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>(?!.*td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>)
```

But it extracts the last part of the string instead of the second:

```
<td class='text-left'>166,774</td>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Many thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're using a *negative* lookahead in your pattern. If you change that to a positive one, you can get what you're looking for in the *second* match:

```
<td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>(?=.*td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>)
```

If you would rather get a single match, you could modify your pattern slightly, e.g. to

```
<td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>(?=<td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td><\/tr>)
```

That should give you the section you need. Note that I'm basing this on the example string you've given, so I can't say how robust this would be.

Answer (score 1):

You get the last occurrence of the td, because `<td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>(?!.*td[^>]*>[^>]*<\/td>)` uses a negative lookahead to match from an opening till closing td while asserting that there are no more td's on the right.

That will match the last occurrence, which is `<td class='text-left'>166,774</td>`

You could make use of the DOM instead of using a regex, which is very error prone. Add a table around the tr, and get the third td in the row.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
let s = `<tr><td><STRONG>A.Total Likuiditas Tersedia (Net)</STRONG> </td><td class='text-left'>297,860</td><td class='text-left'>175,236</td><td class='text-left'>166,774</td></tr>`;
div.innerHTML = `<table>${s}</table>`;
let thirdTd = div.querySelector("tr td:nth-of-type(3)").outerHTML;
console.log(thirdTd);
```